# What's the difference between "Is the song good?" and "Is the song any good?"?

Tags: difference

What's the difference between

> Is the song good?

and

> Is the song any good?

Comment: This site does encourage to provide the research the users have done themselves before asking a question.

Comment: In the context of *Is this comment **any** use?*, the word ***any*** is effectively a "downtoner" (opposite of "intensifier").  All it does is add the implication that the speaker might *already* suspect the answer is going to be ***It's no use at all*** -  ***It's useless***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the song good?

You have no previously formed opinion about the song, and wish to form one depending on the answer.

> Is the song any good?

You have a certain amount of doubt that the song can be (any) good/ of any use.

Consider the definition given by [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/be_any_good)

> ***Be any good:***
>
> - Have some merit:
>
> Tell me whether that picture is any good.
>
> - Be of some help in dealing with a situation:
>
> I don't suppose it would be any good asking Stan.

Answer (score 1):

*Is the song good?*

This asks if the song as a whole is good.

**Example conversation**

Q: Is the latest song by Adele good?

A: Well of course it's good! Adele has never written a bad song. However, it's not as good as *Rolling in the Deep*.

---

*Is the song any good?*

This asks if the song contains some amount of good. Maybe the amount of good is small.

**Example conversation**

Q: Is the song by that new band any good?

A: Well, it has a good hook but the playing is uneven. It's going to need some work before we can release it.

Q: Maybe we should employ some session musicians?

A: Yes, good idea.